# Probleme with Delegate on div and document when dynamic and direct load

Tags: javascript, jquery

The situation

**index.html**

```
 <html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
  <div id="viewContainer">     
      <a class="menu-lnk">Link 1 </a>
  </div>
 </body>
```

**page1.html**

```
  <div id="page1">     
      <a class="page-lnk">Page Link 1 </a>
       <a class="page-lnk">Page Link 2 </a>
       ....
  </div>
```

**lib.js**

```
   $(document).('click','.menu-lnk',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.get('page1.html','',function(response){
          $('#viewContainer').html(response);
      })
    })
```

**The Problem**
 `$('#viewContainer').on('click','.page-lnk),function(){//Code}` works **only** when **page1.html is dynamically loaded**  (what i think it's normal due to the delegate on jquery. but i think it could also when there is direct loading. No ??

When i want to use `$('document').on('click','.page-lnk),function(){//Code}` in this case it'DOES NOT work anymore.

(PS: excuse me for my english, i'm french)